# Unable to access deployed app from Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: deployment, digital-ocean, dokku

## Edit

The issue is resolved, [see this github issue for solution](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/4407). It had to do with my application forcing SSL, while there was no SSL Certificate installed. That's why it was getting connection refused. Moreover, Chrome was redirecting `http` to `https` forcefully.

## Question

I've deployed an app on Dokku using DigitalOcean's droplet, but unfortunately I'm unable to access, I cannot make any requests to my app from outiside the dokku.

Here is the app's server logs, the app server is running on port 5000(inside a docker container, I guess?)

```
2021-01-29T15:54:55.631984450Z app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2021-01-29T15:54:55.632155110Z app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.7.0-p0), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2021-01-29T15:54:55.632257250Z app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2021-01-29T15:54:55.632416330Z app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2021-01-29T15:54:59.477622282Z app[web.1]: D, [2021-01-29T15:54:59.477398 #10] DEBUG -- : BONSAI_URL not present, proceeding with Elasticsearch defaults.
2021-01-29T15:55:01.789462413Z app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5000
2021-01-29T15:55:01.790215291Z app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Here is my port mappings for the app

```
Proxy enabled:                 true
Proxy port map:                http:80:5000
Proxy type:                    nginx
```

Here is my `docker ps -a` output

```
root@dokku-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-sgp1-01:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
29a40b74890a        dokku/propertysafe:latest     "/start web"             23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes                                   propertysafe.web.1
159102b6127b        2ab94a5f043a                  "/bin/bash -c 'mkdir…"   23 minutes ago      Exited (0) 23 minutes ago                       naughty_sammet
a2dc93fff2dd        dd5cbe9f96db                  "/bin/bash -c 'mkdir…"   23 minutes ago      Exited (0) 23 minutes ago                       interesting_margulis
5861efa15abf        cc49b1d8e228                  "/build"                 26 minutes ago      Exited (0) 24 minutes ago                       peaceful_napier
e25ce8a7c7e2        9c8964c4fb67                  "/bin/bash -c 'cat >…"   26 minutes ago      Exited (0) 26 minutes ago                       dreamy_morse
410dbbc9cc4c        b197a493cfba                  "/bin/bash -c 'mkdir…"   26 minutes ago      Exited (0) 26 minutes ago                       crazy_hodgkin
5555c7890af0        gliderlabs/herokuish:latest   "/bin/bash -c 'mkdir…"   26 minutes ago      Exited (0) 26 minutes ago                       eager_meitner
287b083012b6        postgres:11.6                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                  5432/tcp            dokku.postgres.app_db
```

and the `ufw` firewall has permitted `http` traffic.

Everytime I make a hit to the droplet IP I get the connection refused error.

Comment: Is nginx running? You can check if anything is listening on that port by running `netstat -plant | grep LISTEN` and seeing if anything is on port 80.

Comment: yes, it is running. I've also posted it in DigitalOcean's forum, [check here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unable-to-access-app-deployed-on-dokku-in-a-droplet) for further details of the issue and the running services. 
I haven't been able to resolve this so far.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if the Dokku app is not responding to external requests, it is because the app itself isn't allowing external network requests. This can be checked by running:

```sh
# replace $APP with your app name
curl --include $(dokku network:report --network-web-listeners $APP)
```

If the command does not succeed with an expected response, then it is something in your application. If it *does* succeed, then it is likely that something external is blocking requests. In such cases, many users end up having Cloudflare or similar in front of their servers, which may be causing network issues due to misconfiguration.

It is recommended to jump on the [Gliderlabs Slack](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/getting-started/where-to-get-help/) for more direct support for these sorts of issues.

Comment: I get this error on running the command with my app name. `flag provided but not defined: -network-web-listeners
Usage of network:report:
curl: no URL specified!`

Comment: Might be worth jumping onto the gliderlabs slack for help. Folks can come back and update the ticket once we figure out what is going on.

Comment: Diaz the issue is resolved. Your response on the github issue helped me to solve this. I've updated my Question to point to the github issue for the actual solution.